# How to use "or" and "not" in a "while" loop python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use `while` with `not` and `or`, but for some reason my code doesn't work.

```
orientation = ""
while orientation is not "h" or "v":
    print("Type 'h' for horizontal and 'v' for vertical") 
    orientation = input()
    if orientation == "h":
        do_something()
    if orientation == "v":
        do_something()
```

The expected outcome would be, if I was to type "h" or "v" into the input, `do_something()` would be called and the while loop would end, but instead, the while loop continues, and repeats. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `orientation not in ['h','v']`

Answer (score 2):

One way to write this is like so:

```
while orientation not in {"h", "v"}:
```

Alternatively, since you're already checking for `"h"` and `"v"` inside the loop, you could avoid repeating yourself:

```
while True:
    print("Type 'h' for horizontal and 'v' for vertical") 
    orientation = input()
    if orientation == "h":
        do_something()
        break
    if orientation == "v":
        do_something()
        break
```

(possibly changing the second `if` into an `elif` and optionally adding an `else` clause telling the user their input wasn't recognised).